# Azure VM and Office365 Identity

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365

I have a VM in Azure that hosts SQL Server. I'd like to be able to have my machine "see" Office365 users and groups. Is there any way I could effectively domain join to Office365 identity?

Answer (score 2):

if you are in a Hybrid state and syncing objects from a local domain controller, than the same objects in AD are the same objects in Office 365.  So, assuming your SQL server is not domain joined, you could still create a VPN tunnel and access local AD resources, or even deploy say a domain controller in Azure with the SQL box.

**Edit**

Azure AD Domain Services can utilize account in Azure AD.  If you utilize custom OU's the users/groups you create will not be visible to Azure AD, they are only accessible thru Azure AD Domain Services.  I had somewhat confused this point in my original answer.  So to clarify - if you use the default flat OU structure you should be able to utilize the same accounts.  This is an additional service to what you have in Office 365, and there can be additional costs to using this service.

Comment: I second this answer, hybrid deployment is the way to go, Azure AD won't give you the results you want.

Comment: Hi, the comment about Azure AD and Office 365 accounts not being interoperable I don't think is correct. as long as the same Azure AD partition is managing both O365 and Azure it is using the same set of user accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Office 365 uses Azure AD, so as long as the same Azure AD partition is managing both O365 and you Azure subscription you will see the same user and group accounts in both products.

Azure AD has a new service called Azure Active Directory Domain Services, this creates a domain service in a Vnet that you choose so that you can join VMs to your new domain.

Once you have setup Azure Domain Service domain all of the user accounts in your Azure AD Partition (the one managing both O365 and Azure) will be available as users in that domain

if we then join our VMs (your SQL server) to that domain they will be able to use those User accounts.

a lot of work but it is all available now for you to configure. if you have Azure AD Connect running this would also include SYNCD account from on premise

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-ds/

Comment: You are correct.  I had been working with custom OU's, and this is where things get weird with Azure AD domain services. You can't move existing objects into your OU's and anything you create there is not visible to normal Azure AD.  I edited my answer to better reflect that.  Thanks.